# Why does exporting Postman collections export deleted requests?

Tags: postman

I am trying to separate my collections.  To do so I backed up all of my collections.  Then I deleted all but one collection and exported that.  The resulting json file still has ALL of my collections.  I even started over after going to postman site and emptying "Trash".  I deleted all but one collection, closed postman, went to postman site, emptied Trash, reopened postman, it had only the one collection, exported, and again, the json file has ALL of my collections.

Comment: This feels more like something the Postman team should look into rather than a question on SO. Can you raise an issue here please. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues

Comment: Have you deleted the collections from PostmanUI? Or made the change from the exported JSON file?